# Create threaded drill bit from cone

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create something like this.

[image]

This is what I've gotten so far. It's not what I want it to be.

[image]

How can I create the shape like in picture 1?

Comment: Something like [that](http://postimg.org/image/6cxu1sdud/) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll show you how to model it as a one mesh with a clean topology.
[image]

Start with enabling the ***Extra Objects*** add on. Then add a ***Spiral*** (*Add*-->*Curve*-->*Spirals*). Play with its settings in a Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>). 
[image]

Convert your curve to the mesh (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Mesh from Curve*). Fill the gaps with the <kbd>F</kbd> key (enable ***F2*** add on).
[image]

Add the *edge loop* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) as pictured below.
[image]

Use *knife* (<kbd>K</kbd>) to cut away the very top of the *cone*. Make the topology as pitured below.
[image]

Add a loopcut between the other two. Snap the cursor to selection (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*), and scale it evenly with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
[image]

You may now finish modeling and add the edge creases (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or create a topology like the one pictured below to make the edge loops  for creasing work.
[image]

Add final two edge loops to crease the blade even more. Enable *Subsurf Modifier* and *smooth* the faces. You may also cut the bottom of the drill with the *knife* to make its base flat.
[image]

Comment: This is direct towards paul gonet, (because i don't have enough reputation to comment yet) i enabled extra shapes and was frustrated to find the simple spiral curve has been removed and replaced by others which none of them seem to get the same result. I could be blind but it seems that this is no longer a viable solution in the current version of blender.

Comment: In 2.78c, I get the exact same curve as that shown in Paul Gonet's example using Archimedian, Poly and Clockwise for the spiral type, and then setting the other settings the same as his example (turns: 5, steps: 8, radius: 0, radius growth: 2, height: -6). I think the only thing that changed was the old settings weren't named.

Answer (score 12):

I'll present two quick ways of achiving a similar result.

1) From a cone:

### Shwrinkwrap a Spiral

Create a spiral (you can find it in the menue after enabling Extra Object: Extra Curves add-on) in cone's top view whith the wanted features and project it on the Z-axis to the cone:

[image]

Create another guiding profile or duplicate and scale the previous one

[image]

Convert both to mesh and fill faces. Then add an edgeloop and scale the vertices on the XY plane.

[image]

Result:

[image]

2) From scratch:

### Array modifier (Object offset)

The idea is to create a profile curve, duplicate it several times around an axis and it smaller and smaller while it goes up.

First thing: create a spikey profile and move it a little bit far away from the origin that represts our rotation axis location pivot.

If you would like to match a given cone, just build the profile starting from a cone's edge or use it as reference.

[image]

Add an array modifier pointing to an empty

[image]

Increase the number of duplication and tweak the empty's *z-location*, *z-rotation* and *x=y=z-scale* till you are satified with the result

[image]

Make a stacked *Copy* of the modifier, hide the last and apply the first in order to access the baked the geometry. Then create some faces as in the picture:

[image]

Delet all but the created faces and unhide the remaining modifier:

[image]

Notice that you can still seamslessly add new faces with the array modifier to complete the tip.

---

Final result after bisect, matcap, smooth shading and edge split modifier:

[image]

---

If you need to keep the profile always the same size, with a constant theread distance, things gets probably harder. I managed to achieve a result with Sverchock nodes, but the setup really depends on what exactly you want to achieve:

[image]

[image]