# Filling space between two identical curves/mesh

Tags: workflow

I wanted to create a flat coil for a project. I used this workflow: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7090/12883

I copied my first coil. Now I have two coils in two dimensions (the first above the second). The space between those is the third dimension. (Z Axis)

Is there an easy way to fill the space between those spirals?

At the moment I am filling the space between both spirals by selecting four points and filling that part, then selecting the next four points and filling the next part (as you can see in the picture).

For reference:
[image]

Comment: Just a tip: I know, that @miceterminator showed you the best/fastest solution, but you may also fill the gaps using the F2 add-on. Please see the second .gif in my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47044/create-threaded-drill-bit-from-cone

Comment: Note that you'd already have the desired result if you'd *extruded* the original mesh, rather than duplicating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the "Bridge Edge Loops" command.

Comment: This worked even better. With Dontwalk's solution I got some fragments (looked like z-fighting). Your solution had a clean result.

Answer (score 3):

Create one coil in *Edit Mode* select all of the vertices press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and press the letter of the axis you want to extrude in (<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>) and drag your mouse. <kbd>LMB</kbd> to finish.

Comment: Ofcourse, how could I forget that. Easy and straightforward solution.