# How to model the bottle threads?

Tags: modeling

The picture show the threads I want to create on the highlighted object. Problem is I don't know how and tutorials really haven't helped much as most of them seem to be about creating a bolt.

So I was hoping I could get some help on how to do this efficiently.**While keeping the top flat like a water bottle.**
The picture shows the threads I'm after.

[image: nail polish threads]
[image: nail bottle]

Comment: Can you post a reference for what you want?the threads I mean.

Comment: I'm trying to get a picture. The threads are that of a nail polish bottle.

Comment: There are tutorials out there on making a lightbulb. There are threads on the bottom of these lightbulbs...

Comment: Use a spiral curve. Please see my answers to get the idea: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47044/create-threaded-drill-bit-from-cone and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46706/how-can-i-make-a-coil-with-relief-volute

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Using a screw modifier and knife boolean

1. Start off with a cylinder. Duplicate one polygon and separate it off into its own object.
2. Extrude the face out into a box.  Make loop cuts in the box.  Select one face at a normal to the cylinder then invert the selection and delete all the other faces.  You should have a face that's aligned with the cylinder edge and at a normal to it.
   [image]
3. Add a Screw modifier.  Ensure the number of steps agrees with the number of sides on the cylinder.  Adjust the settings until you have the desired spiral for your thread.  Apply the modifier.
   [image]
4. Join the screw and cylinder objects into one mesh.  In edit mode, select the cylinder polygons and click Intersect (Knife) on the Face specials menu.  The screw polygons are no longer required so can be deleted.
   [image]
5. Add a couple of edge loops to the main thread spiral.  Then use the inset polygon tool to bevel out the thread itself.  Adjust the start and end of the thread so there is a smooth transition.
   [image]

The resulting topology leaves 4 ngons, but I like how they subdivide so I leave them in. Converting to all quads is possible with some thought.

[image]

### The final render

[image]

Comment: Cool method! +1 from me. BTW I totally forgot about the 'Intersect (Knife)' tool. Thanks for reminding me this useful feature.

Comment: This looks very cool but I wasn't able to add edge loops on step #5. Also on step 1 - how do you duplicate the cylinder's face along the existing face (not along X Y or Z?) - thanks

Answer (score 15):

You may model it using ***Extra Objects*** and ***F2*** add ons.
[image]

Start with enabling the *Extra Objects* add on. Then add a ***Spiral*** (*Add*-->*Curve*-->***Spirals***). Play with its settings in the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>). Remember to make the ***Steps*** number the same as your cylinder's vertices are. 
[image]

Convert your curve to a mesh (in *Object Mode* press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Mesh from Curve*). Duplicate the newly created mesh and place it below to define the thread's thickness.
[image]

Delete the faces of the cylinder, select the curvy mesh, extrude it with <kbd>E</kbd> and scale (press <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale with the Z axis excluded). Join the meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
[image]

Fill the gaps with the <kbd>F</kbd> key.
[image]

You should end up with something like this. Think about how to make a proper topology to make the edge loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) work.
[image]

Comment: How do you do image 5 where you just drag-fill! Amazing!

Comment: That is the F2 addon

Comment: @fabriced you can read more on the F2 addon in [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42017/2217).

Comment: As of v2.79, there are 4 choices for spirals: Archemedian, Logarithmic, Spheric and Torus. Which one do you mean? Only the Spheric one looks like a spiral but it's not cylindrical

Answer (score 1):

You can always go the hard way in by taking a single vertice and creating a twirl shape with it using extrude (*e*.) put once your are done select the whole shape and extrude down the select everything you have at this point and extrude it into the object. The result won't come out as great but sometimes wasting time in blender is just sort of fun.