# Tears and triangles appear when I try to fill faces

Tags: modeling, faces

I used the bevel after boolean addon, which ended up with the following. There were 1 or 2 faces which went along the entire loop, which didn't look right, so I deleted them and ended up with some holes:

[image]

To fill in these holes, I tried to select the edge loop and press Alt + F, then fixing the normals with Ctrl + N. But there are then tears and triangles appearing in the render:

[image]

How do I fill them in properly to avoid this from happening?

[Here is the blend file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ukqh02b81bs58cg/lightbulb.blend) if it helps.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm quite new to blender.

Comment: Can you show the kind of model that you are trying to do. There might be other alternatives that do not involve using booleans. Boolean operations are notorious for creating topology problems like the one you are having.

Comment: @cegaton Sure I'm trying to create the base of a light bulb, which has a screw around. I managed this in the end but like you said the topology is awful. Do you know of a way without booleans?

Comment: You might want to try the "bridge edgeloops" feature. Select two edgeloops in edit mode, press 'w' to bring up the specials menu and 'e' to bridge edge loops. If the two edge loops have the same number of vertices, it will fill with quads. Otherwise it will fake it with triangles.

Comment: @simonzack you can use a screw modifier read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads

Comment: @cegaton Thanks! Will try that out next time.