# Bottle thread answer doubt

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I'm trying to follow the following answer from the site:
[How to model the bottle threads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads)

I could do almost everything, but when I have to do the (spiral) loop cut the program doesn't allow me and I don't know why and in the answer there is no clarification of how it's done.

[image]

Additional info:
Before I remove the screw (even after doing the knife intersect) I can do the spiral loop ring as the picture shows. 
When I delete it I cannot do the spiral loop cut nor select the linked objects all the spiral with CTRL+L and I have to do it manually.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop-cut won't go all the way around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around)

Comment: Did you do the Intersect(knife) step? find it in Ctrl-F menu.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I did the Intersect (knife) step, but when I select the rectangle and press Ctrl+R, it doesn't display the spiral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it myself.  The problem is that not all of the vertices line up perfectly, so you end up with some rogue unwelded verts, like so:

[image]

See those little evil guys?

To fix it, select all verts and choose Mesh->Vertices->Remove Doubles.  Then adjust the threshold until they all nicely merge.

[image]

Once all the verts are properly welded your spiral select will work.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem! Do you know why these ghost vertex appear?

Comment: I think that the geometry of the spiral doesn't line up exactly perfect, even if it looks like it does, so the intersection cut adds extra vertices.