# Boolean Difference not working as expected

Tags: modifiers

I'm three days into Blender (and loving it!) so please don't be too harsh.
For my small project I decided to create a lightbulb and I'm struggling with the base. My goal was to model a screw thread contact by subtracting a spiral from a cylinder, but I simply can't make it work.

So this is the base
[image]

And this is the spiral that I want to subtract from it
[image]

And here is the final result of the Boolean modificator set to Difference.
[image]

I know this modificator is funky, but still I just don't get what's going on here.
I would highly appreciate any help with where to look at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you added Boolean to both, the **Bottom** part and the **Ring** too.
 Don't add to both of them.

Just add **Boolean** to the bottom part and **pick** your **Ring** thing in it, and change it to **Difference**.