# Convert N-GON to quad with the given topology

Tags: modeling, mesh

I used [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads) to make a screw thread on some cylinder. The acccepted answer poster say that the method will leave 4 ngons at the end, that could be solved to quads with some thoughs. Even if the result is acceptable with thoses ngons, you still can see a little flaw in the shape once subdivision is added.

After many tries I am not getting it right, and more generally, I have a hard time with retopology and understanding edge flow. How would you get rid of thoses ngons ?

[image: Screw thread cylinder topology]

Thanks.

Comment: In this link: https://topology-guides.tumblr.com/ look for "Optimal Edge Loop Reduction Flows"

Comment: Nice link, will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: maybe share your object so that we can give a try