# How can I make a bottle thread?

Tags: modeling

I am a newbie and I don't have enough reputation to add a comment on any previous questions. I'm currently stuck trying to make the bottle thread.

Here is my current situation :
[image]

I tried to do the way that @Xtremity gave on the first video from this question : [How to model the bottle threads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads/238879?noredirect=1#comment405104_238879)

and then, when I try to select the faces that I want and invert it, it also selected the rest of the bottle.
So, what should I do from here and how ?

[image]

This is what I'm looking for :
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to model the bottle threads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads)

Comment: no, it doesnt . as i have mentioned before, i tried to select invert the faces , but then it just select all of the object instead of just the new block that i made specifically for the thread purpose.

Comment: the reason is pretty simple, he separated that face from the rest of the object... select one face you want to start with, press Shift+D to duplicate it an use Right mouse button and select option Separate by Selection, it will make this face into individual object and you can later join it back to bottle

Comment: It's because you still have one object but two loose meshes. If you invert the selection it just selects everything else. Have you followed step 1 exactly? *"Start off with a cylinder. Duplicate one polygon and **separate it off into its own object**."* => key P, *Selection*

Comment: it works ! ! ! thank you @MikoCG

Comment: how do i flip the thread so it goes just like my picture?

Comment: ok i found it , just need to change the angle to -180 degree :) , thank you everyone